# Compile Android NDK project error with Gradle

Tags: windows, jenkins, android-ndk

I have an Android project that has a little CPP code inside.
The server that I'm trying to build this project has the Android SDK and the NDK installed and the dir location was set on the **system variable section**.

When I trying to build the project with gradle I get the following error message:

> Execution failed for task ':mobilecoresdk:compileDebugNdk'.
>
> > NDK not configured.

I understand that gradle didn't found the NDK dir and therefore it's failed.

When i'm trying to build the project on a differnt pc with Android studio I can build it, since the local.properties file is telling gradle where to find the ndk dir, so the only differance in the server is the local.properties file inside the my project which isn't avilable in the server build proccess.

local.properties content is:

> ndk.dir=/Users/avilevinshtein/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
>   sdk.dir=/Users/avilevinshtein/Library/Android/sdk

Should I inject this file on the sever? or am i missing something?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Set those two environment variables before executing:

```
ANDROID_HOME=<SDK_Location>
ANDROID_NDK_HOME=<NDK_Location>
```

If using Jenkisn for building you can use the EnvInject plugin for that.